# Azure Application Insights Tags not showing up in Cost Analysis

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-billing-api

We have Azure Application Insights deployed on our environment and we have put 2 tags to every resource App-Name and Env-Name. All resources are tagged and appearing when we pull the Cost Analysis report by Tags except the Application Insights Alerts (scheduledquery) they show the Tags column as blank.
Below is the screenshot of Cost Analysis and you can clearly see the TAGS column is blank for ALERTS and the next screenshot taken from TAGS section shows that same Alert has TAG applied and these tags are applied like 1 week back and we are pulling recent data on Cost analysis for last 1 day. Any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: When were those tags added? Resource tags only get added to usage data after they're applied to the resources and usage can take 8-24h to be visible in cost analysis. See https://aka.ms/costmgmt/tags. If the tags were added before yesterday and you're seeing cost data since they were added, then you may need to file a support request.

Comment: @MichaelFlanakin as I mentioned earlier in my post the Tags were applied one week back "Alert has TAG applied and these tags are applied like 1 week back ".  I have already the article and thats why I posted as it was more than 1 week and still tags are not showing up.

Comment: Do your tags show up for any other resources? If no tags show up, that's indicative of a different problem than if tags for one service aren't showing up. In either case, you should file a free billing support request.

Comment: One thing you could try is to change the tags. I know this helps unstick some services. Not sure if that applies here, but worth a shot.

Comment: @MichaelFlanakin yep the Tag for e.g. App-Name : Monitoring  appears on the Application Insights Instance level and even on billing its only on these ScheduledQueryRules (alerts) it is not appearing for some reason and thats why I added a new tag instead of App-Name I added Application but still it doesnt show up.

Comment: Definitely file a support request. This sounds like a bug. You can mention you talked to me (I'm from the Cost Management team).

Comment: Thank you @MichaelFlanakin, really appreciate it. I have raised the support case over weekend and I will ensure to mention your name to the Support Engineer.

Comment: hi @MichaelFlanakin I raised the Support Request (Sev-B) but unfortunately the engineer assigned on this case ( Support tkt:120110824000322) has not responded back since last 3 days ..which is weird as I raised this case as Sev-B. I am not sure if you can someway internally look into this supportcase #. I understand its with V- (Tek systems) but thought of checking if you can help.

Comment: Let me take a look...

Comment: FYI - The person assigned to the case is out until Nov 17, so that may be why there's a bit of silence. I pinged him and his manager.

Comment: Thank you so much Michael for the follow up. I will wait until I receive response.